# C++ Ampersand In front of new array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic

So I thought I understood addresses, pointers, and ampersands, and then this happens to me. If I create an array the simple way, and try printing out it's address in a variety of ways, like so...

```
string textArray[5] = {"test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5"};

cout << "Address of string &array: " << &textArray << endl;
cout << "Address of string array: " << textArray << endl;
cout << "Address of string &array[0]: " << &textArray[0] << endl;
```

All 3 lines print the same memory address, as I expected. But if you change the first line to

```
string *textArray = new string[5] {"test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5"};

cout << "Address of string &array: " << &textArray << endl;
cout << "Address of string array: " << textArray << endl;
cout << "Address of string &array[0]: " << &textArray[0] << endl;
```

The address of &textArray is different! So my question is why? Normally in an array, the address is just a pointer to the first element. But this isn't true in a dynamically allocated array? What is that address I'm getting back from &textArray?

Comment: Because `textArray` is a pointer, so you are looking at its address, not the address of the thing it points to.

Comment: The address is just the begin address. You should also print `sizeof(array)` to get an idea where it ends, that will be enlightening.

Comment: Because arrays are  not pointers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`string textArray[5]` is an array of 5 strings, while `string *textArray` is a pointer to a string.

When you print the array name, it decays into a pointer to the first element there by giving the same address as the 1st and 3rd.

While in case of a pointer, when you print its value, it'll print the array's base address, but when you print its address, it'll print the pointer's address itself. **There's no decay of the same entity from one type into another; here, the pointer and array are different entities.**

Answer (score 0):

Because 'char *textArray' isn't an array at all. It's a pointer, with its own address.

Answer (score 0):

it should read:

```
cout <<"Address of a pointer itself: " << &textArray << endl;
cout <<"Address of array pointed to by this pointer: " << textArray << endl;
cout <<"Address of array pointed to by this pointer: " << &textArray[0] << endl;
```

---

> The address of &textArray is different! So my question is why?

because the expression

```
string *textArray = new string[5];
```

creates an array and a pointer which points to it. `&textArray` is address of this pointer itself. Note that in the first case

```
string textArray[5]
```

you didn't assign an array to some pointer (however `textArray` is a pointer itself). If you do

```
string textArray[5];
string *textArrayPtr = &textArray;
```

then you will see the same difference in result as in second case when you try to print `textArrayPtr`:

```
cout <<"Address of a pointer iself: " << &textArrayPtr << endl;
cout <<"Address of array pointed to by this pointer: " << textArrayPtr << endl;
cout <<"Address of array pointed to by this pointer: " << &textArrayPtr[0] ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact these print statements

```
string textArray[5] = {"test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5"};

cout << "Address of string array: " << textArray << endl;
```

and

```
string *textArray = new string[5] {"test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5"};

cout << "Address of string array: " << textArray << endl;
```

are equivalent because arrays are implicitly converted to the pointer to their first elements and string *textArray also points to the first element of the dynamically allocated array.

On the other hand when you use definition

```
string *textArray = new string[5] {"test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5"};
```

then for variable textArray itself the compiler allocates a memory. It does not coinside with the memory occupied by the dynamically allocated array. It is a separate memory. So when you write

```
string *textArray = new string[5] {"test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5"};

cout << "Address of string &array: " << &textArray << endl;
```

you get output of the address of this memory where variable textArray was placed by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

`*textArray` is a pointer, not an array.

`&textArray` refers to the memory address of `textArray`; i.e: the memory location where the `pointer textArray` is located.

`textArray` refers to the data stored in the `pointer textArray`, which is actually the starting address of the array it is pointing to.

`&textArray[0]` again refers to the memory address of `textArray[0]`, which, being the starting address of the array, is the same as `textArray`.

Answer (score 0):

We have two memory sections that my variables save into them . The first storage is stack that in below code `textArray` saved in stack storage , variables that size of them is clear before compiling could save in stack storage.

```
string *textArray = new string[5] {"test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5"};
```

The second storage is heap that you can use this storage when your program is running . You can reserve memory from this storage with `new` keyword . In above code you reserved memory for 5 strings . Note that when you reserve memory from heap storage you must `delete` it , when your using was finished .

Thus `textArray` is name of variable that saved in stack storage . Type of  `textArray` variable is pointer, thus , when you print `&textArray` the output is address of variable that saved in stack section . When you print `textArray` the output is value of `textArray` variable that is a address in heap section that your strings saved in this section. 
`&textArray[0]` tell to compiler my means is `&(*(textArray+0))` , that this is same as `textArray`